# How to do a simple Drag and Drop on Unity Button within screen width and height

Tags: button, drag-and-drop, unity-game-engine

I am an android developer now trying my hands on unity.I am trying to do a simple drag and drop on a Button with the below code ,but as i drag to the extreme ends the button becomes lost ,I need the drag to take place within the screen width and height and only when i drag on the button.Hence i am new to Unity i need your guidance.I got the below code from unity forum

```
public class UserInterface : MonoBehaviour {
public Rect playerPositionRect = new Rect(0, 151, 200, 50);
private Vector2 currentDrag = new Vector2();

void Start () {

}

void Update () {

}

void OnGUI(){
    GUI.Box (playerPositionRect, "MyButton" );

    Vector2 screenMousePosition = new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x, Screen.height - Input.mousePosition.y);
    if (currentDrag.sqrMagnitude != 0 || playerPositionRect.Contains(screenMousePosition)) {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            currentDrag = screenMousePosition;
        } else if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
            playerPositionRect.x += (screenMousePosition.x - currentDrag.x);
            playerPositionRect.y += (screenMousePosition.y - currentDrag.y);

            currentDrag = screenMousePosition;
        } else {
            currentDrag.x = 0;
            currentDrag.y = 0;
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After moving the button you need to make sure its still within the screen. The screen edges is Screen.Width, Screen.Height, 0 and 0 and if its outside we just move it back in. When we are at the right and bottom of the screen we also need to adjust for the buttons height and width.

```
else if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
  playerPositionRect.x += (screenMousePosition.x - currentDrag.x);
  playerPositionRect.y += (screenMousePosition.y - currentDrag.y);

  playerPositionRect.x = Mathf.Clamp(playerPositionRect.x, 0, Screen.width - playerPositionRect.width);
  playerPositionRect.y = Mathf.Clamp(playerPositionRect.y, 0, Screen.height - playerPositionRect.height);

  currentDrag = screenMousePosition;
}
```

Clamp just cuts the value if its outside of the range so for example a x value of -5 would be 0 or a value of 10000000 would be Screen.width - playerPositionRect.width.